# Unable to display data when define array index when using contentful cms

Tags: reactjs, contentful

Unable to get data when using array index with contentful cms

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        partners: [],
    }
}

client = contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
})

componentDidMount() {
    this.client.getEntries({
        'content_type': 'partnersCollection',
        'order': 'sys.createdAt',
    })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                partners: response.items
            })
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}

render(){
    console.log("SIDE BAR RESULT: ", this.state.partners)
    console.log(this.state.partners[0])
    return null;
}
```

`Console.log("SIDE BAR RESULT: ", this.state.partners)` will display all the results from the contentful cms. When use with array index example `this.state.partners[0].fields` error will appear

> Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

Does anyone know why with the array index it will cause error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At initial state - `this.state.partners` is empty array so finding `this.state.partners[0].fields` will give error

you need to put check in render

```
    if(this.state.partners.length > 0) {
         this.state.partners[0].fields
    }
```

Once promise is resolved it will set the `state.partners` in `componentDidMount()`, `render()` will update itself.